# Cannot destructure property 'supabaseUrl' of 'getConfig(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: typescript, authentication, sveltekit, supabase

I followed [@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit](https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/tree/main/packages/sveltekit) guide on how to integrate supabase-auth helpers with sveltekit.

Yet, when running the dev server, I get an internal error

```bash
Cannot destructure property 'supabaseUrl' of 'getConfig(...)' as it is undefined.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'supabaseUrl' of 'getConfig(...)' as it is undefined.
    at getRequestSupabaseClient (file:///.../node_modules/.pnpm/@supabase+auth-helpers-sveltekit@0.8.2_pkve26evzxp6f7qgiud6o7i2nm/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit/dist/utils/supabase-request.js:10:13)
    at Proxy.getServerSession (file:///.../node_modules/.pnpm/@supabase+auth-helpers-sveltekit@0.8.2_pkve26evzxp6f7qgiud6o7i2nm/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit/dist/utils/getServerSession.js:3:22)
    at load (/.../src/routes/+layout.server.ts:6:23)
    at load_server_data (file:///.../node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+kit@1.0.0-next.515_svelte@3.50.1+vite@3.1.8/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/load_data.js:31:41)
    at respond_with_error (file:///.../node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+kit@1.0.0-next.515_svelte@3.50.1+vite@3.1.8/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/respond_with_error.js:40:32)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async resolve (file:///.../node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+kit@1.0.0-next.515_svelte@3.50.1+vite@3.1.8/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:254:12)
    at async respond (file:///.../node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+kit@1.0.0-next.515_svelte@3.50.1+vite@3.1.8/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:287:20)
    at async file:///.../node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+kit@1.0.0-next.515_svelte@3.50.1+vite@3.1.8/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:407:22
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved thx to [github issue](https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/issues/310).

The problem was that I imported `createClient` (in $lib/db) from

`import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'`

instead of

`import { createClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit'`